# C# Почему async/await может тормозить

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

C# async/await

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static object sync = new object();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; ++i)
        {
            KeyValuePair<string, string> pr = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(i.ToString(), rnd.Next(1251000, 1259999).ToString());
            ProcessingTransactionAsync(pr);
        }
    }

    private async void ProcessingTransactionAsync(KeyValuePair<string, string> trn)
    {
        this.WriteLog($"{trn.Key}_{trn.Value}", $"----> 1");

        TestResult trnRes = await Task<TestResult>.Run((Func<TestResult>)(() =>
        {
            this.WriteLog($"{trn.Key}_{trn.Value}", $"----> 2");
            return this.ProcessingTransaction(trn);
        }));
    }

    private TestResult ProcessingTransaction(KeyValuePair<string, string> trn)
    {
        this.WriteLog($"{trn.Key}_{trn.Value}", $"----> 3");

        //Здесь ещё функции, функции, функции 
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        TestResult value = new TestResult();
        this.WriteLog($"{trn.Key}_{trn.Value}", $"----> 4");
        return value;
    }

    #region Additional

    private void WriteLog(string nameLogFile, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            string pathToLog = "Log";

            if (!Directory.Exists(pathToLog))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToLog);

            string filename = Path.Combine(pathToLog, string.Format("{0}.log", nameLogFile));
            string fullText = string.Format("[{0:dd.MM.yyy HH:mm:ss.fff}] {1}\r\n", DateTime.Now, message);
            lock (sync)
                File.AppendAllText(filename, fullText, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251"));
        }
        catch
        {
            // Перехватываем все и ничего не делаем
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

На первой итерации в лог пишется сл.:

> [21.06.2017 16:53:49.998] ----> 1
>
> [21.06.2017 16:53:50.022] ----> 2

При 100 итерации

> [21.06.2017 16:56:44.937] ----> 1
>
> [21.06.2017 16:56:52.672] ----> 2

Что программа может делать так долго(около 8 секунд) между шагами "----> 1" и "----> 2" на 100 итерации? Можно ли это как-то исправить?

Comment: Язык укажите в тэгах

Comment: Потоки в пуле кончились? @andreycha

Comment: @Grundy машина просто не стоядерная :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы запускаете в цикле одновременно 100 тасков (`ProcessingTransactionAsync`): вы не дожидаетесь их окончания. Каждый из них запускает внутренний таск через `Task.Run` на пуле потоков.

Пул потоков работает так: если есть свободный поток, то задание выполняется на нём. Если нет, система пытается создать новые потоки до `MaxThreads`. Если потоков и так слишком много, система думает, что вы просто создаёте задания, не дожидаясь результата, и не создаёт новых потоков, а просто ждёт, пока какой-то из рабочих потоков не освободится, и лишь тогда отдаёт ему задание.

Думаю, у вас случилось именно это.

Comment: Отличное объяснение, спасибо.

Comment: @АндрейКулаков: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, что верно угадал причину.